# Unable to start logstash service" logstash: unrecognized service"

Tags: services, logging

After configuring logstash, when I enter the command `service logstash configtest` it return `logstash: unrecognized service` error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming config is in /etc/logstash and /etc/logstash/conf.d/ use:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/ -t -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
```

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html
for more details